# JavaScript Regular Expression Help: Match 0 or 1 times but do not capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to return just the portion between a # and the first "/" from a URL. Sometimes the URL may not have a proceeding "/". I am struggling to deal with that scenario in a RegEx:

```
var url1 = '#some';
var url2 = '#some/parameter';

var hash = /#(.*)\//.exec(url1);
alert(hash[1]); // only want 'some'

var hash = /#(.*)\//.exec(url2);
alert(hash[1]); / only want 'some'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^/]` to match any character that is not a `/`:

```
var hash = /^#([^/]+)/.exec(url2)[1];
```

In general if you want to group a sub-expression for a quantifier, but don't want to capture it, you can prefix the sub-expression with `?:`, like so: `(?:.*)`.

With the above regex, however, you do want to capture the `([^\]*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var hash = yourString.match(/#([^/]+)/)[1];
```